# base internationalization in xcode

Tags: xcode, localization

I have a project using base internationalization and i add French in the localizations setting. Then i set my system language to `French` and launch my app, it detects the language and uses french resources; but when i set preferred language to `French(Canada)` and launch my app, it doesn't detect the language french and using my second preferred language (English). 
In my last app which is not using a base internationalization, when i reproduce the above steps, all results are as expected. So anyone can tell me what's wrong with the base internationalization and how can i implement with base internationalization as below:

```
fr --> using fr resources
fr-CA --> still using fr resources
```

Comment: Two things: 1) did your last app have an fr_CA.lproj? 2) What you describe happening is actually what I would expect. If a user wants the fallback sequence to be fr_CA, fr, en, then they can list Français canadien, Français, English, in that order, in System Preferences. Since they can then, in the case that they didn't, that fact implies that they really want the fallback order to be fr_CA, en. Put another way, if I as a user really did want to use Canadian French in preference to English, but English in preference to French, how would I arrange for that?

Comment: in my last app, there isn't an fr_CA.lproj. And in the two apps, my preferred language list are the same fr_CA,english, fr.

Comment: @KenThomases. If i want to support all the fr_xxx language, then i need to add all the lproj in xcode? It is unacceptable. But in the old project which doens't use base internationalization, i only need to add fr.lproj and then the app can support all fr_xxx languages.

Comment: Was the development language different in your last app?